# Mirroring In External Hard Drive

Tags: partitioning, backup, external-hard-drive

I've recently bought a Seagate Expansion external hard drive (STBV2000200). Searched the Internet but it's still unclear to me how it actually works.

Does it have two internal 1TB drives ?

Regardless what's inside, what's the best way to backup my data on this drive ? 
Mirror those two internal drives (if there are two at all) ? Should I buy another one (the same model) and mirror them ?

Comment: You should always backup important data to more than 1, or better yet, more than 2 physical HDDs, and one of those backups would ideally be "off-site" in event of fires and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing special about that drive. It's simply a 2TB hard drive in an external case with a USB 3.0 interface.  You would back it up just like you would back up any other hard drive.

If you want to back up the contents of this drive, you'll need another drive of at least the same size. Then use your favorite utility to ensure one is backed up to the other. ([`rsync`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), for example)

Answer (score 0):

the internal drive is actually only one hard drive that is 2TB.  You can either copy your data OR image it over using utilities such as CloneZilla